# Can't access Apache Server through IPv6 from outside

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-22.04

My goal is simple : I just want to access my Apache Web server installed on a Ubuntu Server on a local PC behind my box (Freebox) in IPv6. Using NAT and IPv4, I can access the web server but it's a little bit "headache-able" for me to keep it work with a domain name (OVH) and SSL. So I tried to make it work with IPv6 : the IPv6 of my server is public and I just have to complete the AAAA of the domain name.

The problem is : I searched and tried a lot of things (I learned a lot !) but the problem is still complete, I get a "Unknown adress" from Firefox when trying to reach the server from outside my local network !

The situation :

- Ubuntu server shows the good IPv6 adress when I do hostname -I
- I can ping my machine using a external website (dnschecker for example) from and outside my local network [DNSchecker capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CTco.png)
- Apache is configured to use IPv6 adresses and serve pages when asked from the local network BUT it does NOT work when accessed from outside (my problem !)
- ufw is configured to use IPv6 tables, allows Apache and Apache Full [ufw status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apwa4.png)
- no firewall on my internet box

I'm dry, I don't know what to look for in order to solve this problem. I need help, thanks for your ideas and advices.

@djdomi - 20220907 09:21
The result of lsof -i :80,443. Sounds good ?

```
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
apache2   958     root    4u  IPv6  25783      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2   958     root    6u  IPv6  25787      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
apache2 17616 www-data    4u  IPv6  25783      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 17616 www-data    6u  IPv6  25787      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
apache2 17616 www-data   14u  IPv6 390656      0t0  TCP xxx.com:http->_gateway:39540 (ESTABLISHED)
apache2 17624 www-data    4u  IPv6  25783      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 17624 www-data    6u  IPv6  25787      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
apache2 19938 www-data    4u  IPv6  25783      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 19938 www-data    6u  IPv6  25787      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
apache2 20078 www-data    4u  IPv6  25783      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 20078 www-data    6u  IPv6  25787      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
apache2 20079 www-data    4u  IPv6  25783      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 20079 www-data    6u  IPv6  25787      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
apache2 20080 www-data    4u  IPv6  25783      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 20080 www-data    6u  IPv6  25787      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
apache2 20094 www-data    4u  IPv6  25783      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 20094 www-data    6u  IPv6  25787      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
apache2 20100 www-data    4u  IPv6  25783      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 20100 www-data    6u  IPv6  25787      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
apache2 20101 www-data    4u  IPv6  25783      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 20101 www-data    6u  IPv6  25787      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
apache2 20102 www-data    4u  IPv6  25783      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 20102 www-data    6u  IPv6  25787      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
apache2 20102 www-data   14u  IPv6 388738      0t0  TCP xxx.com:http->_gateway:39556 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Comment: share the output of `lsof -i :80,443`

Comment: Output of lsof shared ! Does it look good ? Thx

Answer (score 0):

"no firewall on my internet box"

There is always a firewall, advanced or really basic and perhaps not clearly outlined if using consumer hardware.

First check, what is the physical piece of hardware that captures inbound WAN traffic? Is this configured to allow inbound IPv6 traffic. Most are still focused towards only IPv4 traffic, and many aren't even capable of handling IPv6 traffic (bin it, upgrade it).

Then trace this logic down the physical hardware stack you have between your ISP and your Local Machine.

Sounds like something is blocking IPv6 traffic from what you've said.

Comment: When I searched informations from my ISP about IPv6, I found my box was ready to handle it. And I understood that I have the option to turn ON the firewall for IPv6 adresses. By default, it is OFF because this is the IPv6 connected computer which handles incoming traffic. So, in my box's configuration, I kept the firewall for IPv6 OFF in order to avoid problems. The NAT and firewall for IPv4 are still ON